Lease Obtained Under False Pretences?
Is it illegal to obtain a lease on a premises by buying the business operating from it but soon afterwards shutting down the business and seeking to buy it outright from its owner so the site can be developed into apartments?
My "grounds" here would be that:

the original owner of the business, as well as the premises' owner, have been misled into thinking that the new business owner was going to continue to use the premises for the same kind of business only.

had the old business owner or the premises' owner known that it was only being acquired cheaply so as to maximize profits from an apartment development, then they would not have entered into a lease agreement at all because they would want to have a much greater share of the apartment development profits - maybe even possibly develop the site themselves. Obviously, it was in the immediate interest of the buyer of the old business to say nothing of their plans lest the premises owner adopt them for themselves.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The business tactics described are perfectly legal.
A company acquiring another company has no duty to disclose their long term motives, and if the contract of sale doesn't impose any requirement to continue the business, then this is not required. Statements about what someone might do in the future are almost never actionable as fraudulent in any way.
The landlord is free to accept or reject the offer to buy the building.
Until the property is sold, the tenant is bound by the terms of the lease that the landlord set forth in the lease. Usually, the landlord has an opportunity to renegotiate the lease terms when a request to transfer the lease to a new tenant is presented to the landlord for the landlord's approval, providing the landlord with an opportunity to prevent the unwelcome situation described in the question with new lease terms.
Expectations about the future course of business of a tenant, which are not lease terms, are not binding. The parole evidence rule prevents them from being considered. If the nature of the tenant's lease reduces the market value of the property to third-parties other than the tenant, reducing the landlord's likely profits in a sale of the premises, that is a function of the landlord's failure to negotiate better lease terms.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
